# "The disk is write protected" kingston usb 3.0

Tags: usb, flash-память

Флешка не открывается, винда запрашивает форматирование, но не может отформатировать, так как "the disk is write protected". Пробовал добавлять в регистр WriteProtect - не помогает. Как быть? (usb 3.0 DataTraveler 100 G3)

Comment: На самой флешке нет переключателей?

Comment: Use Linux - not war.

Comment: Переключателей нету. Хах, то есть если я запущу вирт машину с линухой, то там проблем с флешкой не возникнет?

Comment: "Флешка не открывается, винда запрашивает форматирование" - а сейчас она под какую ФС отформатирована? Похоже она у вас физически сломана просто. На других устройствах она читается без проблем?

Comment: В свойствах не поле ФС пустое. На других не проверял

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях доступ к флешке ограничен правами локальной групповой политики Windows. Рассказываем, как снять защиту в подобной ситуации:

Пуск – Выполнить – gpedit.msc.
В открывшейся панели перейдите к следующему разделу: «Конфигурация компьютера — Административные шаблоны — Система — Доступ к съемным запоминающим устройствам».
Далее вам нужно дезактивировать опцию «Съемные диски: Запретить чтение», переключив в состояние «Отключить».

Comment: gpedit.msc не находит. Искать туториал по установке?

Comment: @Aleksandr, gpedit нет в Windows Home Starter. В принципе, его можно установить с левых сайтов (Microsoft предлагает только обновиться до другой конфигурации). Но не факт, что в результате вы там найдёте то, что нужно: ведь в оснастке будут присутствовать только те элементы, которыми можно управлять в данной конфигурации Windows.